# Scrapy TCP connection timed out issue in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an issue in the "start_requests" function in python. I am using proxy and port for scraping data from another site. But I got:

[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying http://....../> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.

My code is:

```
def get_proxy(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
        settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
        settings['MYSQL_USER'],
        settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
        settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
        charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    try:
        results = self.cursor.execute("SELECT proxy, port FROM geme_proxies WHERE is_active = '1' AND is_deleted = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" )               
        if results > 0:
           row = self.cursor.fetchone()
           return row
        else:
          return

    except Exception, e:
      logger.error('Exception Message: '+ str(e))

def start_requests(self):
    proxy_data = self.get_proxy();
    urls = [settings['OBERWIL_NEWS_URL']]
    for url in urls:
        request =  scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy_data[0] + ':' + proxy_data[1]
        proxy_user_pass = settings['PROXY_USERNAME'] + ':' + settings['PROXY_PASSWORD']
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
        yield request
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, this isn't a proper approach to use proxies in your code. (Free) Proxies die very often or become irrespective without any warning and since you are using a single proxy for loading all of your URLs, if first randomly chosen proxy has any issue(s), you will end up with the error.

A better approach would be to use "rotating proxies" instead:

```
pip install scrapy-rotated-proxy
```

This will allow you to rotate proxies transparently without having to handle middle processes yourself. The approach only requires installing the respository and then gradually updating the proxy list (file: proxylist.txt).

Activate using:

```
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620
```

proxylist.txt:

```
165.22.50.208:8080
139.180.163.43:3128
14.207.137.192:8080
```

Rotating-proxies also have option(s) for switching from file to database along with other useful options for further optimizing your crawlers with respect to target website.